# Best method to select an object from another unknown jQuery object

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors, cross-browser, jquery-traversing

Lets say I have a jQuery object/collection stored in a variable named *obj*, which should contain a DOM element with an id named *target*.

I don't know in advance if *target* will be a **child** in *obj*, i.e.:

```
obj = $('<div id="parent"><div id="target"></div></div>');
```

or if *obj* **equals** *target*, i.e.:

```
obj = $('<div id="target"></div>');
```

or if *target* is a **top-level** element inside *obj*, i.e.:

```
obj = $('<div id="target"/><span id="other"/>');
```

---

I need a way to select *target* from *obj*, but I don't know in advance when to use *.find* and when to use *.filter*.

What would be the fastest and/or most concise method of extracting *target* from *obj*?

What I've come up with is:

```
var $target = obj.find("#target").add(obj.filter("#target"));
```

---

**UPDATE**
I'm adding solutions to a JSPERF test page to see which one is the best.
Currently my solution is still the fastest.
Here is the link, please run the tests so that we'll have more data:

http://jsperf.com/jquery-selecting-objects

Comment: Question: You have target Id in your hand ,then why you have to filter or find from an object ? you could just utilize $("#target")  or document.getElementById("target").(Id is unique for a page ryt ) just asked out of curiosity.

Comment: `$obj.find('#target').andSelf().filter('#target');` ?

Comment: @Jashwant It is still a bit slower than my method. See: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selecting-objects/12

Comment: Yeah, I already checked that. Hence, commented. It's not so slow and is a lot clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ties with the fastest:](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selecting-objects/16)

```
var $target = obj.find('#target').addBack('#target')
```

Comment: Yes, but this version does not find elements that are "grandchildren" of the parent, only direct children. Changing the version to use "find" is actually still a bit slower, see: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selecting-objects/12

Comment: Updated with a solution that is neck and neck with yours; seems a little more readable too.

Comment: Clean, solves the problem and indeed neck-to-neck with my solution. Well done :)

Comment: Nice - that was fun! Thanks for the Question.

Answer (score 4):

What I've come up with is:

```
var $target = obj.find("#target").add(obj.filter("#target"));
```

Currently my solution is still the fastest. Here is the link, please run the tests so that we'll have more data:

http://jsperf.com/jquery-selecting-objects

Answer (score 2):

You can `wrap` the collection with another element and use the `find` method:

```
obj.wrap('<div/>').parent().find('selector');
```

If you're worried about performance, you should not use jQuery in the first place. Vanilla JavaScript is always faster than jQuery.

An alternative is using the `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` method:

```
function find(html, selector) {
   var temp = document.createElement('div');
   temp.innerHTML = html;
   return [].slice.call(temp.querySelectorAll(selector));    
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this indeed faster than making 2 queries?

Comment: Thanks, I just did and the result I got show that 2 queries are indeed faster: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selecting-objects

Comment: @Yosi That's interesting, `wrap` is much slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can start off with a fresh `<div/>` and append `obj` to it, then do the search:

```
$( '<div/>' ).append( obj ).find( '#target' );
```

Of the three, [**this**](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selecting-objects/3) is the second fastest.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the wrap > find solution because it is the most readable (and I doubt you need to optimise performance any further). But performance wise, you should be running only the methods you need, until you need:

```
var getTarget = function(b){
  for(i=0; i<b.length; i++){
    if(b[i].id === 'target'){
      return $(b[i]);
    } else {
      var $target = b.find('#target');
      if($target.length > 0){ return $target }
    }
  }
}

var $target = getTartget( obj );
```

http://jsperf.com/jquery-selecting-objects/6